# Sessions made sense to me before I started reading about them online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The main thing I've gathered from reading about Sessions vs Cookies is that Cookies are stored on the client-side and that sessions are stored on the server-side. If sessions are stored on the server-side, then how does the server ever know which client is theirs? Clearly, something must be on the client-side.

Whenever I use my self-rolled user authentication, I have a `session_token` column in my `users` database table.

Then, this module tends to facilitate sessions for me:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    User.find_by_session_token(session[:session_token])
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
    session[:session_token] = user.session_token
  end

  def logout_current_user!
    current_user.reset_session_token!
    session[:session_token] = nil
  end

  def require_current_user!
    redirect_to new_session_url if current_user.nil?
  end

  def require_no_current_user!
    redirect_to user_url(current_user) unless current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

I believe by sessions being stored on the server-side, they mean the `session_token` every User has. Further, the session hash must be on the client-side. If not, where is it? Notice, I'm storing the session_token of the user like this: `session[:session_token] = user.session_token`. Lastly, if I'm right that the session is on the client-side, how are it and the session_token kept secure?

Lastly, is this the same way sessions tend to be handled on other frameworks (like Django, php frameworks, etc.)? If not, what are some key differences?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Rails security guide has some good information on sessions:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/security.html#sessions

Basically, the session data can all be stored in the cookie (the default) but it's signed with a digest to protect against tampering using a server-side secret (but the cookie data is not encrypted in Rails 3.2, only base64 encoded, though I believe it is encrypted in Rails 4).

The alternative is that only the session id is stored in the cookie, and the session data is stored on the server somewhere (e.g. `ActiveRecord::SessionStore`).

I think the client/server side session options would be widely supported (especially server-side).  Other options for server-side session storage could be memcache shared between servers, or even memory or file storage which would be separate for each web server in a cluster which would mean your load balancer would need to support sticky sessions (to make sure a user's requests were all routed to the same server because the other servers wouldn't know about it).  If I remember correctly, that's what Apache Tomcat was like in the old days for server-side sessions, before clustering support was added.

Comment: So in Rails 3.2, it does go through some securing when being transferred to and from the client-side to server-side?

Comment: The digest is added when transferring cookie from server to client and checked by the server when the client presents the cookie on the next request.  This just means that the session data stored in the cookie can't be changed  without the server knowing about it.  The session data itself can be read on the client side because it's not encrypted (in Rails 3.2).  So you wouldn't want to store a password or anything else sensitive in there.

Comment: Ah, that means that even though the session can be read, you can't change it because the server will know it was tampered with, which wouldn't allow you to fake yourself as the other user anyway, correct?

Comment: I believe so.  You've have to steal the whole cookie. By the way, `config.force_ssl = true` will mean that the cookie shouldn't be transmitted over http, just https, which would help protect against cookie sniffing.  But if someone is into your machine or performs a man-in-the-middle attack and can access your cookies, you're in trouble!  I reckon this would also be the case even if the session data was on the server, and only the id in the cookie - stealing the cookie with the id would also give access to the session.

Comment: Sorry, I should point out that `config.force_ssl = true` will force your entire site to use https.  I believe that there's an attribute you can set on cookies such that they are only transmitted over https connections, independently of forcing your entire site to be https.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are usually implemented by setting the session token as a cookie. It has to be chosen randomly so the user cannot guess another user's token.
All session data is stored on the server together with the associated token.

Comment: You mean to say that the session token is stored as a cookie and on the server. Correct? The associated token you speak of is the session token and that session token is both on the server and in the cookies. Can't someone just look into their cookies? I'm pretty sure if I looked into my friend's cookies while they're on FB, I'd be able to see the session_token as you describe it. This would be very bad.

Comment: How would you look into your friend's cookies?

Comment: If you're on their computer, it's just a matter of knowing how to get to that information.

Comment: If you can already access their computer, why should you care about the token?

Comment: If we're going to play it that way, you should care in case you only have 1 minute, so that later, you could access their FB from your computer having the knowledge that the friend probably never logs out. Look, I'm just looking for the core, I'm not here to play through scenarios. Is the session_token encrypted when it makes its way to the client-side?

Comment: No. It can't be. Where would you store the key?