# How does rails/devise handle cookie sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'd like to understand what's really going on when signing in a user with rails/devise.

I've created a minimal rails app, installed devise and created a `User` devise model.
Everything works fine, and when I log in (using `remember me`) I get a session cookie just as expected.

Now what's bugging me is : How does rails handle the session informations that the browser is passing through the cookie ?

I'd naively expect some information to be stored in the database, but I don't see where. There's no such thing as `session` table, no session column in `Users`, and I couldn't find anything of interest in the `tmp` dir.

Note that restarting the server wouldn't kill my session. It is of course expected, but now I'm really wondering what kind of magic is happening here ?

in other words : how does the server check the validity of a cookie to authenticate a user ?

Thanks !

Comment: Devise stores some information in the database (`last_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_ip`, etc.), but relies on cookies to simulate stateful session consistency overtime. The cookie has a "TTL" or time to live, and that cookie is written to the browser when "remember me" is checked. (This at least is the default/most typical system vis-a-vis Devise, from what I understand.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default rails session storage is CookieStore.  This means that all the session data is stored in a cookie rather than in the database anywhere.  In Rails 3.2 the cookie is signed to prevent tampering, but not encrypted.  In Rails 4 it's generally encrypted by default.  The fact that it's in a cookie is how it persists across restarts of your server.  It also means you can only store 4k of data and you wouldn't want to store anything sensitive in there in Rails < 4.  It's best to keep a minimum of data in the session anyway.

You can also opt for storing the session data in the database and only having a session id in a cookie.

This answer I gave the other week has some extra info that might be useful:

[Sessions made sense to me before I started reading about them online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491464/sessions-made-sense-to-me-before-i-started-reading-about-them-online/21491657#21491657)

Also, the rails api doc for CookieStore gives a nice summary:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Comment: I think when you said "is how it persists across restarts of your server" you really meant "is how it persists across restarts of your browser/client"...?

Comment: I did actually mean across restarts of the server because the question said "Note that restarting the server wouldn't kill my session. It is of course expected, but now I'm really wondering what kind of magic is happening here?", so my point was that the reason it persists across restarts of the server is that it's stored in a cookie on the client and is therefore independent of server restarts.  Of course it can also persist across restarts of the browser, depending on cookie expiry.

Comment: So if I am on rails 4, my application is backend server independent? and its session affinity free?