# Are session, stored in cookies, safe enough to store important information like id of user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing simple authentication. When the user had login, app stored user's id in session[:user_id]. I heard about sessions' encryption, but is it okay? I mean, can user change :user_id in his session to admin's id, for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does rails/devise handle cookie sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783016/how-does-rails-devise-handle-cookie-sessions)

Comment: @TamerShlash, thanks. But the information there isn't very useful for this question. I asked about encryption safety.

Comment: Maybe you should modify your question to better reflect what you're asking about, specifically the title :)

Comment: @TamerShlash, you're right :). I changed title a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, it's not a good idea. 
Especially if people are accessing your site from a public location, or even worse, a public computer. The reason it's 'no' is because of Session Hijacking. You can read about Session Hijacking in section 2.3 of the [Ruby on Rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html). You can get around this somewhat by using https (TLS/SSL). Refer to the guide for more information.

You could use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) or [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). 
These options might be too hard and too long winded for your purpose.

There is a shortcut; to use an already existing well-known authentication and authorization framework like "[Sign in With Google](https://developers.google.com/+/)", which is essentially OAuth2 but you can use the tokens to give users with a google account access to your system. [Here is the Ruby quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ruby).

Regarding encrypting session data, while a nice idea, it's still open for attack unfortunately. Definitely better than just storing id's in the sesssion data. Over at Information Security StackExchange you'll find some good commentary.

> Do you need to encrypt session data?
>   ...
>
> ... You don't need to encrypt it. At most, encryption is a form of
>   obfuscation. You're putting the key on the same system as the data, so
>   it can always be found and extracted.

ref: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18880/do-you-need-to-encrypt-session-data

Comment: I am in a similar boat trying to store user ID’s in the session but reading this post seems to contradict that session state is a safe option. From my understanding session is one of the better methods to store sensitive information that will be reused throughout the app. Can you expand why this logic is wrong?

Comment: As stated, because of Session Highjacking http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html